Access Top Camera in Accurate Scanner using react-native-qrcode-scanner package in react-native?
i have developed a qr scanner in react-native. now i have installed the app in accurate scanners in that scanner it have three cameras(front, back and top) i want to scan the Qr code through top camera.
package: react-native-qrcode-scanner
so how can i do to access the top-camera
import QRCodeScanner from 'react-native-qrcode-scanner';

export default const QRScan = () => {
  const [scannedData, setScannedData] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [isScanning, setIsScanning] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (scannedData) {
      setIsScanning(false);
      Vibration.vibrate(500);
    }
  }, [scannedData]);

  const handleScan = ({data}: {data: string}) => {
    setScannedData(data);
  };

  const startScan = () => {
    setIsScanning(true);
    setScannedData(null);
  };

  const renderCamera = () => {
    return (
      <QRCodeScanner
        onRead={handleScan}
        reactivate={true}
        showMarker={true}
        markerStyle={styles.marker}
        cameraStyle={styles.camera}
      />
    );
  };

  const renderCard = () => {
    if (!scannedData) return null;

    const keyValuePairs = scannedData.split(',');
    return (
      <View style={styles.card}>
        {keyValuePairs.map((pair, index) => {
          const [key, value] = pair.split(':');
          return (
            <Text key={index} style={styles.cardText}>
              <Text style={styles.key}>{key.trim()}</Text>: {value.trim()}
            </Text>
          );
        })}
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
      <View style={styles.content}>
        <Text style={styles.scanInfoText}>
          Scan the QR Code to display the details
        </Text>
        {isScanning ? renderCamera() : renderCard()}
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.scanButton}
        onPress={startScan}
        disabled={isScanning}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Scan</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
});

